# Bind a method after Backbone's fetch event

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model, backbone.js-collections

```
var BasicModel = Backbone.Model.extends({

   url : function() {
       return "/something";
    }

});

var basicModel = new BasicModel();
basicModel.fetch();
```

If BasicModel is a collection, then the follwoing is possible

```
   this.on("add", function (model) {
         console.log(model);
    });
```

Is there any lisiting event I can bind for Backbone model, which get invoked after fetch happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `change` event.

in your model.

```
this.on("change", function);
```

or in your view

```
this.model.on("change", function);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
basicModel.fetch({success:function(){
      //do whatever you want
}});
```